Sitecore Sidekick Could Not Find File AuditLog\_3nh8.tis
I am using Sidekick and get this error when going to the Audit Log UI.
String reference not set to an instance of a String. Parameter name: s

I see this error alongside it and sure enough the file is missing from the directory so unsure how to regenerate it:
Could not find file 'D:\home\site\wwwroot\App_Data\AuditLog\_3nh8.tis'.

I have 4 separate environments and only 2 have this issue (Sidekick installed via NuGet)
The other 2 environments display the Audit Log and do not produce the error messages above. I have rebuilt the Core and Master indexes, restarted the Application, redeployed the application, and tried removing the App_Data\AuditLog directory files to see if they would regenerate but they did not.
I have SolrCloud for our indexes (one SolrCloud environment per Sitecore environment).
The full error is as follows:
[ArgumentNullException: String reference not set to an instance of a String.
Parameter name: s]
   System.DateTimeParse.Parse(String s, DateTimeFormatInfo dtfi, DateTimeStyles styles) +6391135
   Sidekick.AuditLog.Core.LuceneAuditLog.GetUserActivity(ActivityDataModel data) +94
   Sidekick.AuditLog.AuditLogController.UserActivity(ActivityDataModel data) +39
   lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +139
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +35
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__9_0(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState) +40
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +77
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +43
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__11_0() +72
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass11_1.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__2() +396
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass11_1.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__2() +396
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass11_1.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__2() +396
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +43
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass3_6.<BeginInvokeAction>b__3() +42
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass3_1.<BeginInvokeAction>b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +188
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +1879
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c.<BeginExecuteCore>b__152_1(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +73
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +52
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c.<BeginProcessRequest>b__20_1(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +43
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +73
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +39
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +621
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step) +182
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +134


Solr should have nothing to do with this issue. Audit Log is using Lucene and data is stored in App_data. Where are you hosting? PaaS or VM, which Sidekick version? I have just tested  on Azure PaaS and files are regenerated on app start. As side note I would advise to switch to SQL Audit Log instead of Lucene.

The .tis file seems to be where the details of the lucene index are stored. Perhaps temporary for the life of the application. How do the 4 environments differ? Do they all run from "D:\home\site\wwwroot"? It seems to me that you have maybe hard coded the 'Settings.DataFolder" for your local version, then deployed that setting to higher environments? I would expect deployed environments to have release number in folder path.

The structure does not differ per environment, but the filenames do within the audit log directory.

If you look at the GitHub repo for the SitecoreSidekick: https://github.com/JeffDarchuk/SitecoreSidekick
You can see that the default logging mechanism is the LuceneAuditLog. Upon further inspection, you can see that this uses the IndexWriter (from Lucene.Net assembly) to store the logs in a lucene index on the file system. The constructor for this takes a directory as one of its parameters, which in this case is App_Data/AuditLog which is taken from DataFolder sitecore setting.
When correctly setup, the lucene IndexWriter handles writing all of the necessary files to store the index data to disk. Included in these files are files like '_xxx.tii', '_xxx.tis', '_xxx.fdt', '_xxx.fdx' etc. You will see they all share the same initial filename slug _xxx.
If you monitor the 'AuditLog' directory on a successfully running instance and make edits / saves / publishes etc. Then you can see that all the files will change name over time, with the filename slug being repeated across all files, apart from the segments.gen and segments_d. I believe the reason for this, is because thse last two files track which segments have been created over time.
As a test, if you remove one of the files and recycle your instance. Then try and access the sidekick AuditLog, then you will see the 'cannot find file exception' in the sitecore logs. Continued use of the sitecore back end will not result in the sidekick audit log ever working.
However, if you recycle the instance without removing any files. You will see a new filename slug is created for all files. Similarly, if you just remove the segments files, then a new set of files are created.
In your situation, I am guessing you have committed the segments files to your  repository. These segment files have a record within that states the last segment in operation was _3nh8. Then when your instance is firing up, it searches for those corresponding files and is failing.

Thanks Dean, I tried removing one and recycling but it did not recreate. I checked our repo and no segments are there. The filenames are different per environment in the Audit Log directory. I will try some additional tests removing a file and checking the Sitecore logs.

Please try removing all files from the AuditLog directory and recycle the application pool. If the files are not regenerated, then double check the logs to see if any related exceptions.

Tried that once but will do it again. Should I remove the AuditLog too? or just the tis files?

When I was experimenting, I removed every single file and folder within App_Data/AuditLog. Then after a recycle all the files were regenerated. So if no files are created, then it would seem that there is an issue with your deployed files. In that case I would suggest comparing app_config and bin folders between a working environment and failing one

Thanks, I am comparing. This is an Azure PaaS instance. Are you running locally or on a VM?

Running locally
